# post_save called from admin but m2m doesn't get saved

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I got a model which emits a custom signal in some cases when it gets saved.

Running this "post_save" works fine when I'm not updating my items from the Django admin, but when I change them using the admin I see log messages doing all the things it's supposed to. But it doesn't get saved.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992866/django-db-writes-not-happening-immediately-when-running-in-admin-site) which says this is because the admin uses view level locks. So I tried to run `transaction.commit()` as well as adding `@transaction.commit_manually` to the signal handler. Sadly nothing is saved to the database.

**Update**: It's the `m2m` relationship `organisations` below that is not being saved properly. No exceptions or anything raised, just doesn't get put into the database when it's through the admin.

My handler for reference:

```
@transaction.commit_manually  # tried this as both first and second decorator
@receiver(node_moved, sender=Folder)
def folder_moved_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    transaction.commit_manually()
    transaction.commit()

    # When a folder was so moved it became root
    if instance.is_root_node():
        # Copy these organisations to the new root
        inherit_permissions_from = instance.inherit_permissions_from
        print inherit_permissions_from

        instance.inherit_permissions_from = None
        instance.save()
        set_inherited_permissions_descendents(instance, None)

        if inherit_permissions_from:
            for org in inherit_permissions_from.organisations_with_access:
                instance.organisations.add(org)
                print 'add org: {0}'.format(org)

    else:
        instance.inherit_permissions_from = get_who_to_inherit_from(instance)
        instance.save()

    print 'returning'
    print transaction.commit()
```

I'm at the moment at a loss for what to do, in the long run I'm moving away from using the admin for this task because it's a bit clunky for the general workflow, but until I've had time for that I would just like to get it to work.

The only thing I've been able to come up with is setting a flag and running a batch job every once in a while. Or passing it off to Celery, which is not a dependency at the moment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use celery.contrib.rdb   to debug and find out what is really happening

Comment: Any particular reason for rdb in particular? I've stepped through the code with pdb but since it's not raising any exceptions and I'm not well versed in the code of the admin I'm not really sure what to look for. Any suggestions?

In this case what I want the to be run is adding the m2m relationship, which gets output as working when it's being run. But not reflected on the database. :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `save_related` on `ModelAdmin` that calls the `save_m2m` of the form, like:

```
class FolderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FolderAdminForm

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
         # Do my own fancy stuff
```

Comment: Sometimes one feels dumber than a stack of bricks. Of course I could do that since I was looking at overriding all over the place. I'm blaming it on being tired. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got linked to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432385/django-how-to-save-m2m-data-via-post-save-signal?rq=1#comment4839446_4432385) which mentioned that it's probably the forms that is the problem. The form resetting my m2m field after it being saved.

So I did some digging around and tried to create a custom admin form that could do this form me. Sadly it seems to doomed; the admin doesn't do commit on the form. It takes the form, [make it spit out an unsaved object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1088). Then it [takes that object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1105), [saves it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L736) and then finally [takes the form object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1106) and [saves it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L754).

`save_m2m` on form doesn't seem to be overridable. If I [understand the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) correctly `save_m2m` is dynamically added on and since my custom form didn't stop anything I'm for now guessing that is true.

So what I'm going to do now is add a warning that doing what I've been trying to fix is not for the admin and a link to a custom view. And then in the future build away the need for the admin completely for this part of the app. It wasn't meant to be used the way I'm using it I can imagine.

So in the immortal words of MC Hammer; *can't touch this.*

For reference my model form:

```
class FolderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save_m2m(self):
        raise Exception('For the greater good') 

class FolderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FolderAdminForm
```